# Remove unnecessary state lines from SVG file

Tags: css, xml, svg

I am trying to get an SVG file with only the states/counties that are in gray. I am able to do so but have been unable to get it so that there is only a border around the states in gray, and not around anything else.

The first picture below is what it currently looks like with the state borders. However, if I remove the large chunk of code beginning at line 1212 in my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/279qjt1r/ then it will result in the 2nd picture below. It will only be the states I want to see, however there are no state borders so you can't really tell which county is in what state.

Currently, the state lines are set by this line of css:

```
.State_Lines {fill:none;stroke:#221e1f;stroke-width:0.89143497;}
```

How can I remove the border around the whited out states while still keeping the border around the states that I have in gray? So basically, how can I get a border around each state in my second picture I have posted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dude! Seriously....a **minimal** demo is all that is required, we don't need the enitre codebase.

Comment: @Paulie_D I can update it to only show a couple of the states now

Comment: @Paulie_D alright, it is updated now

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the state borders are all in one single path.  There is no way to change that with CSS.  You would need to edit that path in Inkscape. Select the path, then use the path node editing tool (F2) to remove the points in that path that you don't want.